# Visual Studio - See all inherited members

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, inheritance, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 during design time, is it possible to see all members inherited by a class?

If I have something like this:

```
  public class A
  {
       public void AMethod()
       { 
       }
  }

  public class B : A 
  {
      public void BMethod()
      {
      }
  }

  public class C : B
  {
      public void CMethod()
      {
      }
  }
```

If I'm working in class `C` it would be nice to see that it inherits `BMethod` from `B` and `AMethod` from `A`.  Is this information exposed?  Do I need a plugin?

Comment: You can type `this.` in the editor and the it should popup with a list of all available members, methods, etc.

Comment: Intellisense should be doing that for you.  Create an instance of the object and after entering a dot, a full list of members should appear.

Comment: If you type `this.` or `base.` then intellisense should show you what's available.

Comment: There's no other way then typing this in the code editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options I am aware of:

- You can use IntelliSense by typing `this.` or `base.`. A drop down will appear with the member of the current class and it's decendents (`this`) or only it's descendants (`base`);
- You can use the `Class View` (using the menu `View` > `Class View`), to get a breakdown of your class.

Comment: If you right click in the detail section of Class View, you can also select "Show Inherited Members" which I found very useful.

Comment: Useful documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/viewing-the-structure-of-code?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Object Browser for that (View | Object Browser or CTRL+W, J). Via the Object Browser Setting (the Gear icon at the top) you can select Show Inhereted Members. If you select ClassC from your example it will show all inhereted members (also from the class Object by the way). If you then select BMethod it will show that ClassC inherits this from ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

Using the operator can see the base class methods from which to inherit, in this example I have 3 separate files A.cs, B.cs and C.cs

[image]